# Visualising Recamán's sequence using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to visualise Recamán's sequence using semicircles. This is an example of what I'm trying to replicate:

[image]

By manually defining each semicircle, I've got this so far:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=0.5cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [line width=3mm] (0,0) arc (-180:0:1/2) arc (180:0:2/2) arc (-180:0:3/2) arc (-180:0:-4/2) arc (-180:0:5/2) arc (180:0:6/2) arc (-180:0:7/2) arc (-180:0:-8/2) arc (-180:0:9/2) arc (-180:0:-10/2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to code this so it will automatically generate N iterations of the sequence?

In basic terms, the size of the steps increases sequentially, but you subtract if you can (i.e. if you arrive at a number that hasn't been used before), otherwise you add.

[image]

For reference, this sequence is A005132 on 'The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences' - https://oeis.org/A005132

Comment: At pag.21 of the [animate manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/animate/animate.pdf) there is a 3D example with a Lorenz's fly.

Comment: On pag. 640 of the pgf manual there is the Fibonacci sequence.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As I am quite ignorant in TikZ I can't add the colours etc...

- first we generate the first 1000 sequence members,
- second, we use some kind of expandable loop in the tikz picture. For this I loaded `xinttools`, but there are other choices.
- third I did three separate pictures but one can probably use in the same picture successive loops with new colors perhaps, or vary the color with index #1.

I did not abstract into a macro with the number of steps as argument, and I did not do the work to created animated gif, but this could give a start.

Also, I spend a bit time in TikZ manual looking for half-circles, but I got confused, so I stick with the `arc` construct of OP, I don't know if efficient or not for TikZ matters.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=0.5cm]{standalone}

% FIRST WE GENERATE a(n) for n=0, ..., 1000
% https://oeis.org/A005132
\makeatletter
\@namedef{recaman0}{0}\@namedef{namacer0}{0}
\@namedef{recaman1}{1}\@namedef{namacer1}{1}
\@namedef{recaman2}{3}\@namedef{namacer3}{2}
\@namedef{recaman3}{6}\@namedef{namacer6}{3}
% \<namacerN> will give the *last* index n with a(n) = N

\count@ 3
\loop
\advance\count@ \@ne
  \edef\zzz{\the\numexpr
            \@nameuse{recaman\the\numexpr\count@-\@ne}-\count@}%
  \@namedef{recagoleft\the\count@}{0}%
  \ifnum\zzz>\z@ 
     \ifcsname namacer\zzz\endcsname
         \edef\zzz{\the\numexpr\zzz+\count@+\count@}%
     \else
         \@namedef{recagoleft\the\count@}{1}%
     \fi
  \else
     \edef\zzz{\the\numexpr\zzz+\count@+\count@}%
  \fi
  \expandafter\edef\csname recaman\the\count@\endcsname{\zzz}%
  \expandafter\edef\csname namacer\zzz\endcsname{\the\count@}%
\typeout{a(\the\count@) = \@nameuse{recaman\the\count@}}%
\ifnum\count@<1000
\repeat

\usepackage{xinttools}

\makeatletter
% I added the "recagoleft" in a second stage originally I was doing
% \ifnum test to check if increase or decrease for index 2*#1 and
% 2*#1+1
% (perhaps I should have kept more cumbersome \ifnum rather than
%  creating these extra macros?)
\def\mymacro#1{%
  arc
  \if\@nameuse{recagoleft\the\numexpr2*#1}1%
  \expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
    {(-180:0:-\the\numexpr2*#1\relax)}{(180:0:\the\numexpr2*#1\relax)}%
  arc
  \if\@nameuse{recagoleft\the\numexpr2*#1+1}1%
  \expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
    {(180:0:-\the\numexpr2*#1+1\relax)}{(-180:0:\the\numexpr2*#1+1\relax)}%
 }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [line width=3mm] 
(0,0) arc
 (-180:0:1)
 \xintApplyUnbraced{\mymacro}{\xintSeq{1}{10}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [line width=3mm] 
(0,0) arc
 (-180:0:1)
 \xintApplyUnbraced{\mymacro}{\xintSeq{1}{30}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [line width=3mm] 
(0,0) arc
 (-180:0:1)
 \xintApplyUnbraced{\mymacro}{\xintSeq{1}{50}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

For generating the picture I had the problem that my usual gs invocation (with transparent background) proved very slow and produced very big png's... (13M for the third one). So I did it again with smaller resolution and here is the first one (for n=2*10=20, circa).

[image]

For the one up to n=2*50+1=101 I upload a screen capture

[image]

---

I realized only later that `50`(i.e. n=101) was maximal with `1cm` units before triggering "dimension too large error" from TikZ. But this works, where the unit is about `1.5pt` (`2pt` would be too big).

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=100000sp,y=100000sp]
\draw [line width=3mm] 
(0,0) arc
 (-180:0:1)
 \xintApplyUnbraced{\mymacro}{\xintSeq{1}{499}};% and not 500 as a(1001) not pre-computed
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I obtain this, which indicates the values of sequence up to `n=999`: (sorry I initially uploaded a possibly wrong picture because I used 500, hence n=1001 but my pre-computations in preamble go only up to 1000; no error was triggered because only an `\if` test is done about some control sequence, not a computation or an `\ifnum`)

[image]

---

I am almost an expert in TikZ now: a `\draw` statement can have only one colour. So I modified my approach to use some loop to accumulate multiple `\draw` with a colour from an `xcolor` color series.

I wanted to create an animated gif, for this reason I do a super-loop which increases the number of steps each time. My usual `convert` invocation failed, using seemingly the size of the first pdf page. Then I modified the code to use the same picture size for all frames. This is why in the code below I added new macros holding `\max(a(n), i=0..n)`.

But `convert` again failed so I post only here a snapshot of the last frame.

But if you compile to pdf, your PDF viewer possibly with re-create the animation for you by holding down the space key (it works for me; I configured view to a single page i.e. not "continous pages").

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
% FIRST WE GENERATE a(n) for n=0, ..., 1000
% https://oeis.org/A005132
\makeatletter
\@namedef{recaman0}{0}\@namedef{namacer0}{0}
\@namedef{recaman1}{1}\@namedef{namacer1}{1}\@namedef{recagoleft1}{0}
\@namedef{recaman2}{3}\@namedef{namacer3}{2}\@namedef{recagoleft2}{0}
\@namedef{recaman3}{6}\@namedef{namacer6}{3}\@namedef{recagoleft3}{0}
% \<namacerN> will give the *last* index n with a(n) = N
\@namedef{recaMax0}{0}
\@namedef{recaMax1}{1}
\@namedef{recaMax2}{3}
\@namedef{recaMax3}{6}
\count@ 3
\loop
\advance\count@ \@ne
  \edef\zzz{\the\numexpr
            \@nameuse{recaman\the\numexpr\count@-\@ne}-\count@}%
  \@namedef{recagoleft\the\count@}{0}%
  \expandafter\let\csname recaMax\the\count@\expandafter\endcsname
                  \csname recaMax\the\numexpr\count@-\@ne\endcsname
  \ifnum\zzz>\z@ 
     \ifcsname namacer\zzz\endcsname
         \edef\zzz{\the\numexpr\zzz+\count@+\count@}%
         \ifnum\zzz>\@nameuse{recaMax\the\count@}
               \expandafter\let\csname recaMax\the\count@\endcsname\zzz
         \fi
     \else
         \@namedef{recagoleft\the\count@}{1}%
     \fi
  \else
     \edef\zzz{\the\numexpr\zzz+\count@+\count@}%
     \ifnum\zzz>\@nameuse{recaMax\the\count@}
           \expandafter\let\csname recaMax\the\count@\endcsname\zzz
     \fi
  \fi
  \expandafter\let\csname recaman\the\count@\endcsname\zzz
  \expandafter\edef\csname namacer\zzz\endcsname{\the\count@}%
\typeout{a(\the\count@) = \@nameuse{recaman\the\count@}
           (max so far=\@nameuse{recaMax\the\count@})}%
\ifnum\count@<1000
\repeat

\usepackage{xinttools}

\makeatletter
\def\mymacro#1{%
\draw
  [color={foo!!+}]
% radius being n, width of circle 2n, end-point is at 2*a(n)
  (2*\@nameuse{recaman\the\numexpr#1-1},0)
  arc 
  \if\@nameuse{recagoleft#1}1%
  \expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
    {(\unless\ifodd#1 -\fi180:0:-#1)}{(\ifodd#1 -\fi180:0:#1)};%
 }
\makeatother

\makeatletter
 \def\drawframe#1{\noexpand
           \draw
           (0,0)--(0,-#1)--(\the\numexpr2*\@nameuse{recaMax#1},-#1)
            --(\the\numexpr2*\@nameuse{recaMax#1},#1)--(0,#1)--cycle;}%
\makeatother

\definecolorseries{foo}{rgb}{last}{blue}{red}

\begin{document}

\xintFor* #1 in {\xintSeq{1}{100}}\do{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=5mm, y=5mm]
 \edef\zzz{\drawframe{100}}\zzz% get all pictures to be of same size
 \resetcolorseries[#1]{foo}%
 \xintApplyUnbraced{\mymacro}{\xintSeq{1}{#1}}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

Here is thus page 100 of the produced PDF:

[image]

---

I finally manage to get an animated gif:

[image]
Recipe:

- 65 frames,
- `[x=1mm, y=1mm]`,
- each draw with `line width=.5mm`,
- pdflatex
- `convert -density 72 recaman-colors.pdf _tmp%02d.png`
- `convert -verbose -dispose previous -loop 0 -density 100 -delay 15 _tmp0{0..9}.png _tmp{10..63}.png -delay 300 _tmp64.png recaman.gif`

Output not as smooth as one could hope, but <strike>360383</strike> (was for 50 frames) 745256  bytes.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry, really thought these should be spirals. Should have checked. Sorry! With insert path you can, of course, insert whatever you like, also a series of arcs. I have not much time now, unfortunately ...

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\tikzset{Recaman/.style n args={3}{insert path={
foreach \X in {#1,...,#2}
{arc (-180:0:{#3*(2*\X-1)/2}) arc (0:180:#3*2*\X/2) }
}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \expandafter\draw[rounded corners] (0,1) to[out=0,in=90] (3,0) 
    [Recaman={2}{6}{0.3}] arc(-180:0:2) to[out=90,in=90] ++(3,1)
    [Recaman={2}{7}{0.2}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I thought they were spirals as well at first, but actually they are semicircles in the visualisation I'm looking to replicate. See for example, this Numberphile video on YouTube - https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=135&v=FGC5TdIiT9U

Comment: Added some more info to my question post to describe how the sequence is formed.

Comment: @Milo I should have definitely checked before making such a statement. Sorry!